# Unity2d empty object color

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

How to apply a **solid color** to an **empty object** in **Unity 2D** ?

[image: This is the object's image having a Box Collider 2D]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty game object doesn't have any component attached which apply or reflect color.

A simple way to do so,

- Put an empty white sprite of size 10x10 maximum in your project.
- Drop it into scene.
- Add collider what you want.
- Change color or `Sprite Renderer`. Whatever the color would be.
- Resize it according to your need.

Comment: I have added a Sprite Rendered to the object. My object is a rectangular one and my image is square so when i reduce "Pixels per unit" the sprite's size is increasing but is it possible to restrict the sprite inside the object ?

Comment: You don't want to resize sprite but colliders only?

Comment: I think if you follow mention steps in series then I think you problem would be resolved

Comment: in the image I attached to the question there is a re-sized collider but the sprite still is too small, am using a 8x8 pixel sprite as u said 10 is the max

Comment: It is because you are attaching `Sprite Renderer` in existing `GameObject`. Try to create a new `GameObject` by dropping your `Sprite` directly in hierarchy. It will create a `GameObject` then attach colliders, then resize it

Comment: u mean resize the collider or the object itself ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100022/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-andy-the-android).

Comment: resize object itself

Answer (score 0):

Game objects require a SpriteRenderer component in order to show graphics. Once you have attached a SpriteRenderer, attach the solid colored sprite you want.

SpriteRenderer doc: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html